# How to use ModelAttribute across different jsps

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have several controllers. The various pages that these controllers go to need to know what role the user
has.I would like to be able to first get all the user roles. For this reason I am thinking
I need a base controller from which all these controllers extend from.
The base controller will have a ModelAttribute annotated as UserRoles,which would read the user roles.
Now, when the controller creates a ModelAndView should this UserRoles be added to the ModelAndView so
that the jsp can interact with it?

Comment: As you are already using Spring you might want to let Spring-Security handle all that for you.  You can then use The EL hasRole() etc to handle this. http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html

Comment: Thank you! I have seen code where @ModelAttribute is used in a controller and annotated with say@UserRoles. Then in the jsp that the controller directs to, ${UserRoles} is used. How is it visible to the jsp, when it hasn't been added to the ModelAndView?

Comment: You could annotate a method in your Controller with @ModelAttribute. Then you have access to Object returned from this method.

Comment: Thanks s.kwiotek- my question is should the object that is returned from the modelattribute, be added to the modelandview? Bcos I have seen code, where a controller creates a modelandview but the modelattribute is never added to it. However, the jsp is accessing the modelattribute. Also, the jsp refers to the modelAttribute using the annotation.

Comment: Yes it is added to Model by his name e.g. @ModelAttribute("name"). When you want this to access crossover your Controllers, you have to create a Class with Annotation @ControllerAdvice and put this in that Class.